# Converting a 2D numpy array to a STL file

Tags: python, numpy, face-alignment

I am using `[face-alignment][1]` module to get the 2D points of a face, much like DLIB face landmark detector but with Z-Index this time. I want to convert or save that 2D array into an STL file. I am using `numpy-stl` to convert this however from their [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-stl/), whenever I try to write a mesh, it always errors out. Below is my code and the error. Any suggestions beyond `numpy-stl` are welcome as well.

```
import face_alignment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from skimage import io
import collections
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh


# Run the 3D face alignment on a test image, without CUDA.
fa = face_alignment.FaceAlignment(face_alignment.LandmarksType._3D, device='cpu', flip_input=True)

try:
    input_img = io.imread('/home/ubuntu/desOpencv/srkface.jpg')
except FileNotFoundError:
    input_img = io.imread('test/assets/aflw-test.jpg')

preds = fa.get_landmarks(input_img)[-1]

vertices = np.array([\
    [-1, -1, -1],
    [+1, -1, -1],
    [+1, +1, -1],
    [-1, +1, -1],
    [-1, -1, +1],
    [+1, -1, +1],
    [+1, +1, +1],
    [-1, +1, +1]])

cube = mesh.Mesh(np.zeros(preds.shape[0], dtype=mesh.Mesh.dtype))
for i, f in enumerate(preds):
    for j in range(3):
        cube.vectors[i][j] = vertices[f[j],:]

# Write the mesh to file "cube.stl"
cube.save('cube.stl')

# 2D-Plot
plot_style = dict(marker='o',
                  markersize=4,
                  linestyle='-',
                  lw=2)

pred_type = collections.namedtuple('prediction_type', ['slice', 'color'])
pred_types = {'face': pred_type(slice(0, 17), (0.682, 0.780, 0.909, 0.5)),
              'eyebrow1': pred_type(slice(17, 22), (1.0, 0.498, 0.055, 0.4)),
              'eyebrow2': pred_type(slice(22, 27), (1.0, 0.498, 0.055, 0.4)),
              'nose': pred_type(slice(27, 31), (0.345, 0.239, 0.443, 0.4)),
              'nostril': pred_type(slice(31, 36), (0.345, 0.239, 0.443, 0.4)),
              'eye1': pred_type(slice(36, 42), (0.596, 0.875, 0.541, 0.3)),
              'eye2': pred_type(slice(42, 48), (0.596, 0.875, 0.541, 0.3)),
              'lips': pred_type(slice(48, 60), (0.596, 0.875, 0.541, 0.3)),
              'teeth': pred_type(slice(60, 68), (0.596, 0.875, 0.541, 0.4))
              }

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax.imshow(input_img)

for pred_type in pred_types.values():
    ax.plot(preds[pred_type.slice, 0],
            preds[pred_type.slice, 1],
            color=pred_type.color, **plot_style)

ax.axis('off')

# 3D-Plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
surf = ax.scatter(preds[:, 0] * 1.2,
                  preds[:, 1],
                  preds[:, 2],
                  c='cyan',
                  alpha=1.0,
                  edgecolor='b')

for pred_type in pred_types.values():
    ax.plot3D(preds[pred_type.slice, 0] * 1.2,
              preds[pred_type.slice, 1],
              preds[pred_type.slice, 2], color='blue')

ax.view_init(elev=90., azim=90.)
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[::-1])
plt.show()



    cube.vectors[i][j] = vertices[f[j],:]
```

The error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

If I remove the `numpy-stl` codeblock this is the output in matplotlib.

[image: Output from matplotlib]

Comment: Can you add the *full* traceback?

Comment: the section above the image, titled "the error" is the full traceback, I am not getting anything else.

Comment: Really? A traceback usually has a bit where it shows you where it occurred